# VBA Runtime error 1004 while setting a range

Tags: excel, vba, range

Basically I'm trying to optimize the process of copying values in dynamic ranges.

This is what I currently have and it works:

```
For i = 0 To 6
    Worksheets("S").Cells(wstaty, (4 + i)).Value = Worksheets("B").Cells(id, (13 + i)).Value
Next i
```

I would like to replace iteration with faster method, which example is:

`Range("A1:A5").Value = Range("B1:B5").Value`

But when I try:

`Worksheets("S").Range(Cells(wstaty, 4), Cells(wstaty, 10)).Value = Worksheets("B").Range(Cells(id, 13), Cells(id, 19)).Value`

I get

> Run-time error 1004

So I've decomposited the statement to find out where problem is, so I have:

```
Dim r1, r2 As Range

        Set r1 = Worksheets("S").Range(Cells(wstaty, 4), Cells(wstaty, 10))
        Set r2 = Worksheets("B").Range(Cells(id, 13), Cells(id, 19))  ' <-- error here
        r1.Value = r2.Value
```

and debugger says an error occurs at Set r2 line, which doesn't make much sense to me

(variable ID is always > 2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells(…) is related to the current worksheet. So to be safe you better always address a range with its full name. In your example it would be

`Worksheets("B").Range(Worksheets("B").Cells(…), Worksheets("B").Cells(…))`
   etc.

To avoid lengthy code I would propose to use a variable for the sheet instead.

Comment: Thanks. I've also solved it by eliminating Cells completely: `Worksheets("S").Range("D" + CStr(wstaty) + ":J" + CStr(wstaty)).Value = Worksheets("B").Range("M" + CStr(id) + ":S" + CStr(id)).Value`